# Is there a simple and well-understood explanation of "Homogeneous Coordinate"?

Tags: math, graphics, computer-vision

I know that homogeneous coordinate is used to make affine transformation easy, but 
have no idea how ... and feel confused about its representation : it presents the
point with coordinate (x, y, z, P), why a additional number P is here?What's the 
meaning of P when P = 0 or 1 and even 2、3、4 。。。？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `P!=0` then you can always scale the coordinates to have `P=1` and interpret the remaining coordinates as a point in 3D space. The choice of `P=1` is arbitrary, any fixed nonzero value would serve the same purpose, but among the non-zero real numbers `1` as multiplicative unit and additive generator of the integers has a special role, so why not use it here too.

If `P=0` then the scaling is undetermined by this coordinate. One can scale the first three so that the point (x,y,z) lies on the unit sphere. For various reasons this point can be interpreted as a point at infinity. Note that (-x,-y,-z) represents the same point. One way to see it is that (x,y,z,t) where t is very small is the 3D point (x/t,y/t,z/t,1) which goes to infinity when t goes to 0.